# Understanding Example 1.9 in Hatcher's Vector Bundles book

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I don't understand what the "clutching function" in this example is actually doing. What does it mean to "read off the coordinates of $v_{-}, w_{-}$ in the $v_+, w_+$ coordinate system"? What is the formal equation for $f$? Also, why is it that when "going around the equator", the "angle of rotation when viewed from above" (which angle is this exactly???) goes from $0$ to $4\pi$?

I'm new to studying vector bundles, so this picture-argument is just really confusing. I think I will understand it better if the explanation is more formal (and less handwavy).

[image]

Comment: A vector bundle can be thought of as a bunch of overlapping local trivializations glued together with vector space isomorphisms.  Here, $(v_+,w_+)$ and $(v_-,w_-)$ are two local trivializations of $TS^2$ that can be extended to include a neighborhood of the equator (the details of these don't matter too much--just come up with trivializations of the north- and south-hemispheres), and the clutching function is the basis-change function on the overlap (with terminology evoking gear teeth being meshed together).  This function says how the local trivialization at the equator is supposed to work.